# Heap sort print out 0 instead of supposed array element

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out an input array sequence number in an ascending order using heap sort when I encounter some error.

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void swap( float a[],int i, int j){
    float temp = a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
}

void PushDown (float a[],int first, int last){
    int r = first;
    while (r<=last/2)
        if (last==2*r){
            if (a[r]>a[last]) swap(a,r, last);
                    r=last;//break
        }
        else
            if ((a[r]>a[2*r]) && (a[2*r]<=a[2*r+1])){
                    swap(a,r,2*r);
                    r=2*r;
            }
        else
            if ((a[r]>a[2*r+1]) && (a[2*r+1]<=a[2*r])){
                    swap(a,r,2*r+1);
                    r=2*r+1;
            }
        else r=last; //break;
}

void HeapSort(float a[],int n){
    int i;
    for(i = (n-2)/2; i>=0; i--)
        PushDown(a,i,n-1);
    for(i = n-1; i>=2; i--) {
        swap(a,a[0],a[i]);
        PushDown(a,0,i-1);
    }
    swap(a,a[0],a[1]);

}

//NHAP DAY SO
void Nhapdayso(float a[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Nhap so thu %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);
    }
}
//IN DAY SO
void Inday(float a[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%.f ",a[i]);
    }
}

//CHUONG TRINH CHINH
int main(){
    int n;
    float a[50];
    printf("Nhap so phan tu cua day so: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Nhapdayso(a,n);
    Inday(a,n);
    HeapSort(a,n);
    printf("\nDay so sau khi sap xep : ");
    Inday(a,n);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:
Example:
testcase: 1 9 5 3
expected output: 1 3 5 9
actual output: 1 0 5 9

testcase: 12 99 50
expected output: 12 50 99
actual output: 12 99 50

testcase: 78 46 2
expected output: 2 46 78
actual output: 2 46 0

I suspected s.t is wrong with my PushDown function but I just couldn't figure it out.

Your aid would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thai giadinh,  Aside: Why the '.' in `printf("%.f ",a[i]);`?

Comment: With `if (a[r]>a[last]) swap(a,r, last);  r=last;//break`, is indented `r=last;//break` meant to be part of the `if(a[r]> ...)` block or not?

Comment: `swap(a,a[0],a[i])` is wrong, try `swap(a,0,i)`

Comment: You are supposed to pass indices, not the values themselves, to `swap()`. Lines 35 and 38.

Comment: In addition to what @n.'pronouns'm. wrote, `swap(a,a[0].a[1]);` should be `swap(a,0,1);`. Well, it should really be `if (n > 1) swap(a,0,1);`.

Comment: n. 'pronouns' m comment solve my problem, thanks dude